# Android: keep blue background after ListView selection xml definitions

Tags: android, listview, styles

I'm confused with the answers to this question.

I have the following in values-14/styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />

 <style name="ListTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/br_listitem</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

then I have defined in my drawable dir br_listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@color/SlateBlue" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

and finally in my listitem.xml file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
   android:layout_width="600dp"
   android:gravity="left|center"   
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   style="@style/ListTheme"
   android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">
```

I get a light orange color when pressed and light green after.  The activated background works, but it's not using my colors...

Thanks !
~ Jay

Based on comments I made the following changes. I pulled the style out of the LinearLayout and put it in my listview as follows:

```
 <ListView 
    style="@style/ListTheme"
    android:id="@+id/XYZList" 
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_rowSpan="10"     
    android:focusable="true"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:background="#80D0D0D0"
    >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be applying the ListTheme to the listview? Not the linearlayout?

Comment: That certainly makes sense, I changed my listview as suggested, with the same results as before